# Why does BCP export utility write output file in chinese?

Tags: bcp

I'm using the BCP utility to write SQL data to an output file. At random, some of the file contents are written in Mandarin (or so it seems), while the rest are written in English.

Here is the command I run from command prompt:

```
bcp.exe "SELECT * FROM MyTable" queryout "C:\Temp\MyTableExport.txt" -
e"C:\Temp\MyTableExport_Error.txt" -T -c -t, -S [server IP] -d [database]
```

Any idea why some of the files are outputting content in a different language?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bcp.exe "SELECT * FROM MyTable" queryout "C:\Temp\MyTableExport.txt" -
e"C:\Temp\MyTableExport_Error.txt" -T -w -t, -S [server IP] -d [database]
```